# Mech Fingers mesh folds into itself

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image: Mech fingers bend problem]

I'm having a problem with the hands with the Rigify generated rig(using the deformation rig) as this is a mecha robot, the fingers are clipping into itself too much. I tried fixing the vertex groups on the hands and nothing. As I can't seem to find any answer for this, is there a way I can have more mechanical fingers that won't deform as much like that of a human finger would with Rigify rig?

Comment: Here is the file if anyone wants to take a look at the problem: https://pasteall.org/blend/210dab92b3fa43c49cdfcd163830d9fa

Comment: for machines you should use Parent > With Empty Groups rather than With Automatic Weights, this way you're sure that it won't deform like something organic

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to add that this is Parented with Empty Groups which is odd of why its bending the way it is.

Comment: mmh it seems like it's parented With Automatic Weight, for example each hand is one object, phalanx are not separate, so each finger phalanx can't behave like separate objects

Comment: when I first was figuring out the rigging, I first tried "With Automatic weights" but it gives me the Bone Heat Error. So yeah its parented with Empty Groups. Should I use a different rig then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reparent *With Automatic Weight* it will works rather fine, so the solution may be to make hands separate objects, parent *With Automatic Weight*, then if necessary join back to the rest:

[image]

If you don't want to reparent *With Automatic Weight* for some reasons, then you need to give some manual corrections in order to extend a bit the influence of each bone. First thing, display the layers with the bones that deform your mesh and the ones that command:

[image]

You need then to extend a bit the influence of each phalanx, before:

[image]

After:

[image]

It will work better:

[image]

Use the *Paint Mask* option to make it easier to paint on the right faces, also make sure that you enable all the options that allow to paint through (in the N panel):

[image]

You can also do all the corrections through the *Vertex Groups* list and Assign button, which may be quicker:

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you. Ok going to try this out and I'll let you know if I can get the same results